# I am trying to alter a type in object relational model to add a member function to it, but it keeps giving me errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, object-relational-model

This Emp_t type is the one I want to alter

```sql
create type Emp_t as object(
eno number(4),
ename varchar2(15),
slary number(8,2),
dependents Dependtb_t,
edept ref Dept_t
);
/
```

This is the DDL commant to alter Emp_t type

```sql
alter type Emp_t
add member function calChildAllowance(eno number(4)) return float
cascade;
```

But it gives me this error:

> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
> ORA-06550: line 12, column 49:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
> := . ) , @ % default character
> The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
> ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
> PLS-00565: EMP_T must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)

[image: Image of the error attached here. I am using SQL Command Line for this]

I wanted to alter the Emp_t type to add a member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not need precision in number data type:

```
alter type Emp_t
add member function calChildAllowance(eno number) return float
cascade;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it worked! But wont it affect when I execute this method since the data type of 'eno' in the schema is number(4)

Comment: I do not believe it will.

Comment: Hi @UdithKanchana You are welcome, happy to help. If the answer is useful to you you can upvote the answer. Also if it is correct for you you can mark it as correct.

Comment: It is not that you "do not need" the precision; it is syntactically invalid to include the precision in a function signature (both for a member function of a type or for a stored function).